# Calling Redux actions in react view

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to **pass a variable to a Redux action**, but the action is receiving **undefined**, what am i doing wrong?

index.js - **where i'm calling the action**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as documentActions from '../../services/redux/actions/document'

function Document(props) {
    return (
        <ul className="list-group group">
            <li className="list-group-item group-item" 
                name = 'group'
                onClick={() => props.toggleDoc(1)}>
                {props.data.name}
            </li> 
        </ul>
    )
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        selectedId: state.selectedId
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        toggleDoc: () => dispatch(documentActions.toggleDoc())
    }
}
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Document)
```

document.js - where the action is

```
import * as types from '../types'

export function toggleDoc(id) {
  return {
    type: types.TOGGLE_DOC,
    payload: id
  }
}
```

reducer

```
import * as types from '../types'

const initialState = {
  selectedId: null
}

export default function toggleDoc(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log('action')
  console.log(action.payload)
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.TOGGLE_DOC:
      return {
        ...initialState,
        selectedId: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What prints:
[image]

what should print:
action
1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`props.toggleDoc` is defined in `mapDispatchToProps`. You have defined it as this:

```js
toggleDoc: () => dispatch(documentActions.toggleDoc())
```

This definition does not accept any arguments, even though `documentActions.toggleDoc` can. You need to change the definition to pass along that argument:

```js
toggleDoc: (id) => dispatch(documentActions.toggleDoc(id))
```